# multiple yaml files in ros2 launch

Tags: yaml, launch, ros2

there is a possibility to load 2 yaml files in launch file like in ros1?

in ros1 i can do

```
<node name="node1" type="node1" pkg="pkg1" output="log">
        <rosparam command="load" file="$file1.yaml"/>
        <rosparam command="load" file="$file2.yaml"/>
    </node>
```

i want to know if we can do the same in ros2 (foxy)
i know that i can load one file like this

```
def generate_launch_description():
    path_file = 'test.yaml'
    file_parameters = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory('pkg1'),
        'config',
        path_file
        )

    return LaunchDescription([
        Node(
            package="pkg1",
            executable="node1",
            name="node1",
            output="screen",
            parameters=[file_parameters
            ]
        )
    ])
```

there is a way to load 2 yaml files in ros2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can simply define another path for the second .yaml and append it to the parameters.

Example:

```
def generate_launch_description():
first_path_file = 'test.yaml'
second_path_file = 'second_test.yaml'
first_file_parameters = os.path.join(
    get_package_share_directory('pkg1'),
    'config',
    path_file
    )
second_file_parameters = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(
    ('pkg1'),
    'config',
     second_path_file)

return LaunchDescription([
    Node(
        package="pkg1",
        executable="node1",
        name="node1",
        output="screen",
        parameters=[first_file_parameters, second_file_parameters
        ]
    )
])
```

Mind that you can define parameters for multiple nodes in one .yaml, this could be a cleaner solution.